# bash try/catch behaviour bash -ex << EOF ... EOF or Here Documents and variable expansion

Tags: bash

I'm not a bash expert and can not really describe my problem. That's why I show you my script:

```
#!/bin/bash -x
bash -ex << TRY
  VAR1="123"
  echo "$VAR1"
TRY
echo "exit code: $?"
```

When I run the script, it produces the following output:

```
+ bash -ex
+ VAR1=123
+ echo ''

+ echo 'exit code: 0'
exit code: 0
```

My problem: Why is the variable VAR1 not assigned in echo command? I would expect the following output:

```
+ bash -ex
+ VAR1=123
+ echo ''
123
+ echo 'exit code: 0'
exit code: 0
```

Comment: This isn't really exception handling. It's just a separate program that can abort early, and it only works if the script being passed to `bash` doesn't need to read from standard input at all.

Comment: that's all I need for my use case, thanks for clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `$VAR1` gets expanded even before going into the bash instance, by the current shell.

Quote `TRY` as below if you don't want the variables to be expanded from outside. (You can use either single or double quotes.)

```
bash -ex << "TRY"
  VAR1="123"
  echo "$VAR1"
TRY
```

From the [Bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Redirections)

> 3.6.6 Here Documents
>
> This type of redirection instructs the shell to read input from the
>   current source until a line containing only word (with no trailing
>   blanks) is seen. All of the lines read up to that point are then used
>   as the standard input (or file descriptor n if n is specified) for a
>   command.
>
> The format of here-documents is:
>
> [n]<<[-]word
>           here-document delimiter
>
> No parameter and variable expansion, command substitution, arithmetic
>   expansion, or filename expansion is performed on word. If any part of
>   word is quoted, the delimiter is the result of quote removal on word,
>   and the lines in the here-document are not expanded. If word is
>   unquoted, all lines of the here-document are subjected to parameter
>   expansion, command substitution, and arithmetic expansion, the
>   character sequence \newline is ignored, and ‘\’ must be used to quote
>   the characters ‘\’, ‘$’, and ‘`’.
>
> If the redirection operator is ‘<<-’, then all leading tab characters
>   are stripped from input lines and the line containing delimiter. This
>   allows here-documents within shell scripts to be indented in a natural
>   fashion.

Answer (score 1):

Since your `Try/Catch` is a heredoc, the shell does variable expansion. 
Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash -x
bash -ex << \TRY
  VAR1="123"
  echo "$VAR1"
TRY
echo "exit code: $?"
```

This can too be achieved by quoting the heredoc token. However, If you want variable substitution performed, don't quote it.